# Nhibernate and Mysql. Insert child uniqie entity

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have related tables.
For example - 
`Worker (id, mame, idWorkerType, ...)` and `WorkerType (id, code (unique key), ...)`

Then I have same classes, that was mapped.

Then, i have list of generated objects like this

- Worker1

  - Id1
  - Name1
  - WorkerType1

    - IdType1
    - CodeType1
- Worker2

  - Id2
  - Name2
  - WorkerType1

    - IdType1
    - CodeType1


    ...

The logic is as follows:

```
foreach (var Worker in Workers)
{
    var WorkerTypeFromDB = GetWorkerTypeByField("Code", Worker.WorkerType.Code).FirstOrDefault();
    if (WorkerTypeFromDB == null)
    {
        session.Insert(Worker.WorkerType);
    }
    else
    {
        session.Update(Worker.WorkerType);
    }

    var WorkerFromDB = GetWorkerByField("Code", Worker.Code).FirstOrDefault();
    if (WorkerFromDB == null)
    {
        session.Insert(Worker);
    }
    else
    {
        session.Update(Worker);
    }
}
```

So, in first iteration I inserting WorkerType1 and Worker1.
In second iteration I updating WorkerType1 (because same unique Code) and trying insert Worker2... but I can't!
I get exception - **object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave.**

I know, that, it happened because i don't insert WorkerType, but I dont need that. I already has WorkerType1 in db.

Сan somebody explain me how resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but we have to fix the (in)appropriate reference handling. Once we know, that object exists in DB *(has the same "CODE")* and we have it loaded in a `session`, we should use that object *reference*.

So the change should be like:

```
var WorkerTypeFromDB = GetWorkerTypeByField("Code", Worker.WorkerType.Code).FirstOrDefault();
if (WorkerTypeFromDB == null)
{
    session.Save(Worker.WorkerType); // Save/Insert not existing
}
else
{
    Worker.WorkerType = WorkerTypeFromDB // assign the existing to our object
}
```

So now, once we have the existing object, we are assigning it as a property `WorkerType`

To handle the Worker, we can do even more: `Merge()` in case that `Worker` already exists.

```
var WorkerFromDB = GetWorkerByField("Code", Worker.Code).FirstOrDefault();
if (WorkerFromDB == null)
{
    session.Save(Worker); // insert not existing
}
else
{
    // here, we should assign the existing Worker ID to passed one
    Worker.ID = WorkerFromDB.ID; // current worker has same identifier
    session.Merge(Worker);       // both will be merged, latest changes will be applied      
}
```

And at the end, when `session.Flush()` is called, all changes will be persisted. (Merge could be used even for WorkerType... as required)*

Read more about `Merge()` here [9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached), An extract:

> ... using `Merge(Object o)`. **This method copies the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier**. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. The method returns the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, NHibernate will save it and return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance does not become associated with the session. **In most applications with detached objects, you need both methods, SaveOrUpdate() and Merge()**.

Comment: Great if that helped ;) Enjoy the NHibernate.